# Google Cloud Run: Connect two services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis

I am experimenting with building a flask app and deploying on Cloud Run.  This app will use Redis as a cache.  I have successfully created a service using a redis container (it appears to be running).  What I cannot figure out how to do is to connect to it.  When I try to ping the redis database using redis-py and the service url,

```
redis_host = 'https://rediscontainerurl.a.run.app'
redis_port = 8080
redis = redis.StrictRedis(host = redis_host, port=redis_port)
redis.ping()
```

I get: "ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to https://rediscontainerurl.a.run.app:8080. Name or service not known."

When I look at the Service log, I do not see any evidence that my ping even reached the service.

If I enter the url into a browser window, I get "Service Unavailable" and I do see the access attempt in the log.

So, two questions:

Is what I am attempting even possible?

If so, what could I possibly be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several points in your question

- Firstly, when you reach a Cloud Run service, you do it ONLY on the port 443 (HTTPS protocol). Of course, internally your service (your container) is exposed on a custom port (8080 by default) but in front of your internal service, a layer is applied (Google Front End, or GFE) that proxies the connection (and host the SSL certificate, check the authentication, create the entry in the DNS,...) and expose your service externally.

-> The port 8080 is not open on your service, your error is normal, reach it on the port 443 (or put nothing if your URL prefix is `https`)

- Secondly, I'm quite intriguing about your REDIS service on Cloud Run. AFAIK, REDIS is a in memory database, and Cloud Run is a stateless and ephemeral container, which can be provision and destroy at any time. The service can scale up and down,... So, how have you configured your REDIS server (and your Cloud Run service) to achieve correctly what you want?

Comment: I removed the port and still no luck.  Apparently I have something else going wrong. I am accepting your answer because did confirm that the url is the method to reach a service.  Thanks!

Comment: You are also right in that the data in the Redis instance would not be persisted. However, in my app, the data would only be needed during a browser session.  That being said, in this instance I was mostly just experimenting with a Redis service on Cloud Run.  I had originally planned to use a managed offering.  For this, I wound up using Redis Cloud rather than continuing to try get the CR service to work.